# What are "18 minute" matzot?

Tags: passover, time, matzah

From my understanding, the dough becomes chametz if it is **not** baked within 18 minutes. So, aren't **all** matzot 18 minutes? Like the words of the seder, what makes the "18 minute" matzot different from all other (non shmurah) matzot?

Comment: Many think dough doesn't necessarily become chametz after 18 minutes

Comment: @DoubleAA - is this a common opinion, now?

Comment: I think it's just marketing/another way of saying it's not chametz...

Comment: (There are plenty of chametz/non-kosher for passover matzot on the market for the rest of the year)

Comment: Perhaps בצק החרש אם יש כיוצא בו שהחמיץ הרי זה אסור: גמ' אם אין שם כיוצא בו מהו א"ר אבהו אמר ר' שמעון בן לקיש כדי שילך אדם ממגדל נוניא לטבריא מיל ונימא מיל הא קמ"ל דשיעורא דמיל כממגדל נוניא ועד טבריא

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=46&format=text

Answer (score 9):

> In current matzah parlance, “18-minute matzah” means that the entire matzah line is cleaned every 18 minutes

https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/getting-to-know-your-matzah/